# Full control of list item bullets in css - ordered and unordered lists

Tags: html, css, html-lists, listitem

How can I change color / size / display-character of `<ol>` or `<ul>` list bullets while maintaining separate control over the rest of the list item?

Solution should handle changes to both list types.

p.s. I've seen a few closely related questions on this matter and wanted to give an inclusive solution (two main variations) to the general problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1 - `<ul>` unordered lists: replace original bullet with your own**

- Upside: requires little change to code.
- Downsides: doesn't control individual list items, does not work with ordered lists (see option 2).

**Step 1.** First get rid of existing list bullets:

```
ul {
   list-style: none;
}
```

- Basic options include (disc, square, circle)
- Less Basic - use image: `ul { list-style: square inside url("sqpurple.gif");` - [try it](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_list-style)
- Another img example - 16px Spinner bullets (paste in 'try it' code):
  `list-style: square inside url("http://agroportal.lirmm.fr/assets/spinners/spinner_000000_16px-4f45a5c270658c15e01139159c3bfca130a7db43c921af9fe77dc0cce05132bf.gif");`

**Step 2.** add a replacement before list item information:

```
ul li:before {
       content: "•";        // change what you like
                            // 'before' does not change li styles

       font-size: 150%;     // a few options
       padding-right: 5px;
       color: blue;
    }
```

Note: it might be better to use [Unicode](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/) "\002022" instead of "•"

**Alternatively**: use another symbol, webding, icon-font favicon.ico image, etc.

```
ul li:before {
       content: "4"; font-family:"Webdings";
    }
```

Another Example: [FontAwesome icon](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/) - after you [get-started](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/) add:

- `content: "<i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>"  // fontawesome API`

**Option 2 - `<ol>` ordered lists: keep original item numbering / lettering but break the list style from `<li>`'s content style using `<div>` or `<span>`**

- Upsides: works for ordered lists, control each list item individually or collectively.
- Downsides: tags for each `<li>`, less bullet control.

**HTML**

```
<ol class="ol--bullet-style">
  <li><div class="li--default">Foo</div></li>
  <li><div class="li--default">Foo</div></li>
  <li><div class="li--default">Foo</div></li>
</ol>
```

**CSS:**

```
.ol--bullet-style {
    color: red;          // some options
    font-size: 150%;
    font-decoration: underline;
    font-family: Courier New;
}

.li--default {
    font-family: Garamond;
    font-size: 100%;
}
```

Or go basic with a div or span tag that does not include a class and use this in your css:

```
ul li div {
    color: blue;
}
```

NOTE: a `<p>` tag is not recommended since it comes with its own special defaults.